# Is there a better way to tell when to stop watering by drip line?

Tags: watering

I have the edges of my garden hilled up so I can keep watering, and keep watering until pools begin to appear in between the trenches. Is this a good way to water the garden with a drip line every few days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can control the time when water comes, **only water during the night**.
Then if you have an input from temperature, **only water when its above 80°F**.

From experience, I know that watering too much can be armfull.

It really depends what you intend to do.

- if you want to grow vegetables in the intensive way, then you might want to water all the time and have chemicals around to fix the moisture induced illnesses and slushes.
- if you want to waste as few water as possible, then you should plant things that are adapted to your region's climate. And instead of watering, use vegetable cover, that will both avoid water evaporating and prevent wildness to grow around your loved plants.